# Missing headers in macOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: macos, catalina

What happened to header files after Catalina update? I am getting the error "assert.h:No such file or directory". In Mojave this issue was solved by using macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg package. Is there any such package for 10.15 or any other solution? Is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: Any updates or solution?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15

Comment: I ran : **xcode-select --install**.  That seemed to have fixed the problem for me. .

Comment: @SanjayNath please add that comment as an Answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I also updated to **Catalina** and got the same problem.
As it was mentioned there is no equivalent package **macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg** for Mac OS 10.15 which solves the problem for **Mojave**.

There are several things you can do which worked for me.

1. Always try

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
2. Some answers recommend to agree with the license. I'm not sure if it's helpful but I did it anyway

   ```
   sudo xcodebuild -license
   ```

   and type *agree*.
3. Apparently you can find these headers in a **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include** directory. So you can add it to some environment/build system variable.

Comment: How can we tell the OSX to look for the common headers in this new directory? Normally you do not need to specify where the headers are. I use CLion and never had to do it

Comment: I'm struggling with this on Big Sur on an M1 Mac mini, so my problem is a little different, but I'm missing EXTERN.h and ended up here.  To answer @HectorEsteban, you would normally set the CPPFLAGS env var to a value like "-I//Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include" (without the quotes, and note the dash-capital-i at the beginning of that value".  WFM when compiling other UNIX-y code and I need to include headers in non-standard locations.